# Get validation errors on a partial's form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

So I have a form in my Rails app that's on a `_form.html.erb`.

I'm displaying this partial on every page of my site, so it doesn't really have any model logic behind it, and the User created form it is made on the fly in the view:

```
<%= form_for User.new, :validate => true do |f| %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><%= f.label :invitation_token, "Invite Token" %></td>
      <td><%= f.text_field :invitation_token, :placeholder => "From your inbox&hellip;".html_safe %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><br><%= f.submit "Sign Up" %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

**I have some validations in my User model, but how would I display those validation errors in my view after reload?**

*I've tried `User.new.errors.inspect` but the messages parameter is always empty, even if there's a validation error.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. Since you will likely want to render these error messages in many places, create a shared folder in your views `app/views/shared/_error_messages.html.erb` and add this partial:

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li>* <%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Now in your view add the code to render the error messages in you form just below `form for`

```
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
```

Comment: But what do I put in place of object if I'm creating Invitation.new on the fly?

Comment: You dont put anything in place of object. The error message partial can be used with any model object. It will catch whatever object has the error message. So If you have a validation in the User model like `validates :invitation_token, presence: true`, then if the form is submitted with a blank invitation token field then it will render the error that "invitation token can not be blank. It might be hard to explain. just implement it and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: In other words the variable `f` in the form can access the the object created by `User.new` through `f.object`. You can use the same error message partial in any form with any model